# Event not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game and for my startscreen code there is a module called event to handle the mouse click on the button to start the game. But when I run my code, it says event is not defined. It was working fine before this but I decided to go from three while loops to one while loop that will call functions of each screen which I think will be better for restarting the screen. Now when I run it it says that event is not defined in this block of code. Thanks.
This is the code that it says is not working:

```
def StartScreen():
    win.blit (menu,(0, 0))
    button1 = pygame.Rect(200, 400, 100, 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, [255, 255, 255], button1)
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_pos = event.pos
        if button1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            player.start = False
            player.run = True
    Text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Start!", Text)
    TextRect.center = ((250), (425))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

And here is my new while loop:

```
while True:
    if player.start == True:
        Start()
    if player.run == True:
        Run()
    if player.gameover == True:
        GameOver()
```

Please ask if you want the full code.

Comment: Can you share the actual error message? Where is the [mcve]? Please see: [ask]. Variable and function names should follow generally the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Looking at that loop, what do you think if statements do?

Comment: What is missing here? Is the issue solved? Is the answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) to get the events at the begin of the main application loop and pass them the functions:

```py
while True:

    events = pygame.event.get()

    if player.start == True:
        Start(events)
    if player.run == True:
        Run(events)
    if player.gameover == True:
        GameOver(events)
```

Add an event loop to the functions for the different stages of the game:

```py
def StartScreen(events):
    win.blit (menu,(0, 0))
    button1 = pygame.Rect(200, 400, 100, 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, [255, 255, 255], button1)

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = event.pos
            if button1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                player.start = False
                player.run = True

    Text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Start!", Text)
    TextRect.center = ((250), (425))
    win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
```